# How can I find all the invoices that has at least 5 transactions and all the latest 5 transactions are in status 'paid'?

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class ChargeOverInvoice(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(db_column='Id', max_length=18, primary_key=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='CreatedDate', auto_now_add=True)


class ChargeOverTransaction(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=80, verbose_name='Transaction #',
                            default=models.DEFAULTED_ON_CREATE, blank=True, null=True)
    chargeover_invoice_id = models.CharField(db_column='ChargeOver_Invoice_ID__c', max_length=255)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Account, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Customer__c')
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(ChargeOverInvoice, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ChargeOver_Invoice__c', blank=True,
                                null=True)
    status = models.CharField(db_column='Status__c', max_length=255, verbose_name='Status')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='CreatedDate', verbose_name='Created Date')
```

I can get the result if it was about filtering within dates like this

```
ChargeOverTransaction.objects.filter(status='Failed (decline)', created_date__lte=now()-relativedelta(days=35)).values('customer', 'invoice', 'chargeover_invoice_id').annotate(total=Count('id')).filter(total__gte=5)
```

But not sure how can I get the latest 5 and add validation on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [window function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.Window) to find five latest transactions for the invoice.

And use [django-cte](https://github.com/dimagi/django-cte) to filter the result.